# DNS stop working for PHP - restart apache fix it temporarily

Tags: php, apache, dns

I'm experiencing a very weird issue with our PHP application and DNS/Apache.
The PHP application that connects to external services (like email, payments etc) suddenly stopped working.
After troubleshooting a while we identified that was a DNS issue. Replacing the address for the IP of the servers we connect to would make the application to work fine.

However the DNS is working fine from the server itself. We can ping, host, wget etc using the name instead of IP.
I created a simple test in PHP to test if it was a PHP issue:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("http://www.google.com", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    echo $buffer;
}
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

That also worked fine.
Restarting the apache service fix the problem for a while but after a few hours the problem happens again.
Checking syslog, apache logs and php logs I can't find anything that might be causing it.

I've checked the /etc/hosts.deny, /etc/hosts, firewall and /etc/nsswitch.

Our apache is version: Apache/2.4.7
And we use PHP 5.5.9

Any ideas of what could be causing the DNS stop working for PHP/Apache ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: [What OS?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532) There's some recent issues with an Ubuntu bug affecting PHP dns lookups, which appear to be workroundable with an apache restart

Comment: Hi Mark, the OS is 14.04.1 Ubuntu. I will check this link you posted there! Thanks

Comment: [Other bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with version 2.19-0ubuntu6.10 of libc-bin

They have relased a newer version:

```
    eglibc (2.19-0ubuntu6.11) trusty-security; urgency=medium

      * REGRESSION UPDATE: Previous update introduced ABI breakage in
        internal glibc query ABI
        - Back out patches/any/CVE-2015-5180-regression.diff
          (LP: #1674532)

 -- Steve Beattie <sbeattie@ubuntu.com>  Tue, 21 Mar 2017 03:28:13 -0700
```

This should resolve your problem

Comment: Here's the Ubuntu Security Notice: https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-2/ and the Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me!!